# Problema para instala el SDK de mercado pago en LARAVEL 8

Tags: mercadopago, laravel-8

A la hora de instalar el SDK en un proyecto que no usa laravel sino php puro todo bien.

El tema es que al querer instalarlo usando el comando:

```
composer require "mercadopago/dx-php"
```

En mi proyecto con laravel 8 (que uso con jetstream) me tira el siguiente error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - mercadopago/dx-php[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.1] require doctrine/common ^2.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[v2.6.0, ..., 2.13.x-dev].
> - doctrine/common[v2.6.0, ..., 2.8.x-dev] require doctrine/inflector 1.* -> found doctrine/inflector[v1.0, ...,
> 1.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.0.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it
> as an argument for the update command.
> - doctrine/common[v2.9.0, ..., 2.13.x-dev] require doctrine/inflector ^1.0 -> found doctrine/inflector[v1.0, ...,
> 1.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 2.0. 3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it
> as an argument for the update command.
> - Root composer.json requires mercadopago/dx-php ^2.2 -> satisfiable by mercadopago/dx-php[2.2.0, 2.2.1].
>
> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades,
> downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific
> versions.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

Lo que hice es actualizar mi composer y sigue el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Resolví mi problema es este el código:

```
composer require mercadopago/dx-php --with-all-dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

El mismo error pero con Lumen 8 de laravel en mi caso eliminé la carpeta vendor y escribí directo en el composer.json en la parte de los require la dependencia de mercado pago después ejecute en comando composer update con esto actualiza y vuelve a crear el vendor y fuerza a descargar el sdk de mercado pago.

Porqué creo el problema es que varias dependencias de mercado Lumen o laravel usa las más actualizadas y mercado pago requiere unas versiones inferiores

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu caso com esse comando

PHP 5.5.0

composer require mercadopago/dx-php:1.2.1 --with-all-dependencies

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Tanto las respuestas como las preguntas deben estar en el idioma del sitio.